# Passing password during git clone from shell script

Tags: git, shell

I have written a shell script to clone the project from multiple location which is sent as a file.
I read the file and pass the each location in a loop and perform my operation.

LocationFile.txt

```
Project1=https://enduser1@stash.my.org/my/path/testProject1.git
Project2=https://enduser2@stash.my.org/my/path/testProject2.git
Project3=https://enduser3@stash.my.org/my/path/testProject3.git
Project4=https://enduser4@stash.my.org/my/path/testProject3.git
```

Password.txt

```
Project1=password1
Project2=password2
Project3=password3
Project4=password4
```

I have a password file encrypted and stored in server, which I can read as part of script and passing into my script
When I run my script during clone step its prompting for a password, I tried to pass the password like below which is not working

```
##############
gitpassword=$password1 #retrieved from Password.txt

for xxx
    do
    ...
    ... 
    git clone "${ProjectArrayList[1]}" 
    read $gitpassword
    ...
    ..
    done
##############
```

I know I can do password less if I use ssh, which I don't want to do.
Is there a way to achieve this with my exsiting approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) and `send` functions to simulate user input automatically.

Here is what the syntax would be like:

```
expect -c 'spawn sudo git clone "${ProjectArrayList[1]}"; expect assword; send "password\n"; interact'
```

Answer (score 1):

Git has a "credential helper" that can do the job [it is designed to work over https].

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store and https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/